# Changing buffer of GtkTextView

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

I have created two `GtkTextBuffer`s in Glade and their texts are already filled from Glade. I'm trying to change `GtkTextView`'s content according to `GtkComboBoxText`'s index. Following callback for `GtkComboBoxText`'s signal `changed` is giving segmentation fault.

All these widgets are retrieved from builder using `gtk_builder_get_object`

```
// inside main()
 g_tv_eula_content = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "tv_eula_content"));
 g_cbt_eula_lang = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "cbt_eula_lang"));
 g_tb_eula_en = GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "tb_eula_en"));
 g_tb_eula_de = GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "tb_eula_de"));
// end of inside main() 

// g_cbt_eula_lang: combo box text
// g_tv_eula_content: text view
// g_tb_eula_en, g_tb_eula_de: text buffers

void cbt_eula_lang_changed_cb() {
  gint index = gtk_combo_box_get_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(g_cbt_eula_lang));
  // printf("index %d\n", index);
  if(g_tv_eula_content) {
    switch(index) {
      case 0:
        if(g_tb_eula_en)
          gtk_text_view_set_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(g_tv_eula_content),g_tb_eula_en);
      break;
      case 1:
        if(g_tb_eula_de)
          gtk_text_view_set_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(g_tv_eula_content),g_tb_eula_de);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what am i missing or doing wrong?

Comment: This is what is frustrating about the builder interface, you can never be sure quite what is hidden behind it. In prior versions, you would need to ensure storage was allocated for both buffers `g_tb_eula_en` and `g_tb_eula_de`, with, e.g. `gtk_text_buffer_new (NULL);`. I can't tell you if `gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "tb_eula_en")` does that, but that is something you need to check. If it isn't reserving storage for the buffer -- then a SegFaulut makes sense when you attempt to use that buffer with a TextView.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I decided to load content from text files. At least this way i will not define any `GtkTextBuffer` but edit text view's . I still wonder why this did not work though.

Comment: I suspect the `gtk_builder_get_object` just returns a pointer to the object. You can create the text buffers on the fly and swap them in/out of the textview as you intend. You just need to make sure the buffers are properly created. You create the buffer, then an iterator to the start `gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset (buffer, &iter, 0);` and then just `gtk_text_buffer_insert (buffer, &iter, "whatever text you want\n", -1);`  The iterator is just `GtkTextIter iter;`.

Comment: The way I always handled creating the buffer and textview is with `buffer = gtk_text_buffer_new (NULL);` and then `text_view = gtk_text_view_new_with_buffer (buffer);` using the default buffer. and swap buffers with `gtk_text_view_set_buffer (text_view, buffer);`

Comment: It is probably not causing the issue but the correct signature for callback og `changed` signal looks different according to the [manpage](https://people.gnome.org/~ryanl/gtk/html/GtkComboBox.html#GtkComboBox-changed). No need to use global variables for everything.